Generic planar sections of a projective variety
In an article by Broberg and Salberger, it is stated that

The set of pairs $(\Lambda,F)\in\mathbb G(k,n)\times \mathbb P\left(\mathbb Q_d[X_0,\ldots,X_n]\right)$ for which $\Lambda\cap V(F)$ is irreducible, of dimension $k-1$, and of degree $d$ is a Zariski-open subset of $\mathbb G(k,n)\times \mathbb P\left(\mathbb Q_d[X_0,\ldots,X_n]\right)$.

where $\mathbb Q_d[X_0,\ldots,X_n]$ is the vector space of homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials, and $\mathbb G(k,n)$ the set of $k$-planes in $\mathbb P^n$. I have tried to figure out the case $k=n-1$, which is the one I'd like to understand most, but I couldn't get very far, and couldn't find any reference. I can't seem to express irreducibility as any sort of polynomial condition. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit : so far I have been able to find that, if I write $A_i=\mathbb P(\mathbb Q_i[X_0,…,X_n])$ for simplicity, and for $i< d$ write
$$\phi_i:(A_1)^{n-k}\times(A_{d-1})^{n-k}\times A_i\times A_{d-i}\rightarrow \mathbb G(k,n)\times A_d$$
$$(f_j,Q_j,C,D)\mapsto\left(V(f_j),CD+\sum f_jQ_j\right)$$
then $\phi_i$ is a polynomial map, whose image is those $(\Lambda,F)$ where $(F \text{ mod } I(\Lambda))$ has a factor of degree $i$, and so the union of all of their images is those $(\Lambda,F)$ where $\Lambda\cap V(F)$ is reducible.
However $\phi_i$ is only well-defined on the open subset where the $f_j$ are linearly independent, which means it is defined on a quasi-projective variety, and its image need not be a variety… I’m quite stuck as to how to proceed further.

We are saying open, not closed here, so we are not trying to express irreducibility as a polynomial condition, but reducibility.
Instead of doing this directly, try cheating a little and using the beautifully useful fact that the image of a projective variety is a projective variety. Then decompose the reducibles into a finite union over the various factorization-shapes of a polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$ variables.

So if I look at the map $\mathbb P\mathbb Q_{d-k}[X_0,\ldots,X_n]\times \mathbb P\mathbb Q_{k}[X_0,\ldots,X_n]\rightarrow \mathbb P\mathbb Q_{d}[X_0,\ldots,X_n]$, I get by your comment that the set of polynomials which have a factor of degree $k$ is in fact a variety, and hence taking the union over $k\leq d$, that the set of reducible polynomials is a variety. That is already very helpful, but what about the planar sections ? I’d be glad to get an extra hint.

I will think about it! Re-reading my hint, I sounded too confident that it would definitely work, and I'm not sure of that. I'll let you know if I think of anything.
